# Formatting a Phone number

Tags: c#, regex, formatting, phone-number

How can I format a phone number from (###)###-#### to ##########? Is there best way to do that? I can use `String.Substring` to get each block of  numbers and then concatenate them. But, Is there any other sophisticated way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a simple Regex replace?

```
string formatted = Regex.Replace(phoneNumberString, "[^0-9]", "");
```

This is essentially just a white list for numbers only. See this fiddle: http://dotnetfiddle.net/ssdWSd

Input: (123) 456-7890

Output: 1234567890

Comment: The `+` is unnecessary, as the function will look for all substrings which satisfy the regex specified and replace it.

Comment: @wei2912 You're right, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it using LINQ:

```
var result = new String(phoneString.Where(x => Char.IsDigit(x)).ToArray());
```

While regex also works, this doesn't require any special set up.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be:

```
myString = myString.Replace("(", "");
myString = myString.Replace(")", "");
myString = myString.Replace("-", "");
```

Replace each character with an empty string.

Comment: This won't work as it assumes strings are mutable, which they aren't.

Comment: I always forget that.  Does my edit work?

Comment: It would work now. The -1 is not from me.

Comment: It's cool.  It was wrong earlier, and whoever it was probably won't come back.  I can't believe how often I forget strings aren't mutable in c#.  Sometimes it takes me 15 minutes of debugging before it hits me.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"^\((\d+)\)(\d+)-(\d+)$", "$1$2$3");
```

***REGEX EXPLANATION***

```
^\((\d+)\)(\d+)-(\d+)$

Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
Match the character “(” literally «\(»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\d+)»
   Match a single character that is a “digit” (0–9 in any Unicode script) «\d+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the character “)” literally «\)»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(\d+)»
   Match a single character that is a “digit” (0–9 in any Unicode script) «\d+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the character “-” literally «-»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 3 «(\d+)»
   Match a single character that is a “digit” (0–9 in any Unicode script) «\d+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Assert position at the end of the string, or before the line break at the end of the string, if any (line feed) «$»

$1$2$3

Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 1 «$1»
Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 2 «$2»
Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 3 «$3»
```

Comment: Care to explain the down-vote ?